# What further research can the result of gene variation detection be used for

Tags: genetics, gene-expression, genomics, gene, copy-number-variation

We do a research on a particular cancer (for e.g. breast cancer). Now, we have a result for the gene variation detection (VCF file). What next steps do we need to do? We don't have a clear picture about this. Can you give us some directions or few papers as an example? (of course it is a huge number but just mention a few). Thanks!